# How to retrieve Twilio Flow Options results

Tags: c#, twilio

I have a Twilio Flow that works fine, I need to retrieve at the end of the flow all answers/options selected by user in order to send all these answers to Sql server via  Azure function.

My question is how can I retrieve all the flow options/answers that were chosen by the user at the end of the flow using C#

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried so far. It will increase the changes of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Studio with Event Streams to capture this information. There is a blog post here that can help get you started.

You can give your Studio widgets meaningful names that help you trace the consumers path through the flow.

[Streaming Studio Flow Executions with Event Streams](https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-studio-event-streams)

Comment: Thanks Alan for your answer, but unfortunately it support only Node.js and I need to capture Flow result using C#

Comment: It is language agnostic. Event streams integration can be done using webhooks or kinesis streams. Quickstarts:

Kinesis Quickstart
https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/eventstreams-quickstart

Webhook Quickstart
https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/webhook-quickstart